# Erlang: Faster way to sum bytes in a binary

Tags: erlang

Below is simple implemenation that adds bytes of a binary. It is slow according to eprof (takes about 10% of total time - mostly because of many calls to `binary:part/3`).

How can this be optimzed ?

```
calc_checksum(Packet) when is_binary(Packet)->  
    calc_checksum(Packet, 0).

calc_checksum(<<>>, Acc) -> 
    Acc band 16#FFFF;

calc_checksum(Packet, Acc) when is_binary(Packet) ->        
    W = binary:decode_unsigned(binary:part(Packet, 0, 2), little),
    NextAcc = Acc + W,
    NextBytes = binary:part(Packet, byte_size(Packet), -(byte_size(Packet)-2)),
    calc_checksum(NextBytes, NextAcc).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more elegant solution is:

```
calc_checksum(<<W:16/little,Rest/bytes>>, Acc0) ->
    Acc1 = Acc0 + W,
    calc_checksum(Rest, Acc1);
calc_checksum(<<>>, Acc) -> Acc band 16#FFFF.
```

This code will generate an error if the binary contains an odd number of bytes. Using pattern matching usually gives better more elegant code.

Comment: I agree. Even more elegant than  <<W:16/little, NextBytes/binary>> = Packet

Answer (score 2):

Using pattern matching instead of calling functions in `binary` seems to double the speed in the pseudo-benchmark I tried in the shell.  Something like this:

```
calc_checksum(Packet, Acc) when is_binary(Packet) ->
    <<W:16/little, NextBytes/binary>> = Packet,
    NextAcc = Acc + W,
    calc_checksum(NextBytes, NextAcc).
```

(I might be wrong, but you should get equivalent results if you set `NextAcc` to `(Acc + W) band 16#FFFF`, which should avoid bignums if you run this on really big binaries.)

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed faster and the code is much more elegant!

Comment: Maybe building a utility function that takes care of the `is_binary` predicate speeds up execution too, as it does not have to check the condition every function call.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla - I tried that but no difference (tc says it takes 1 microsecond to execute is_binary)

Comment: The `is_binary/1` test is true for the empty binary `<<>>` so you will get an error when you reach the end of the binary.

Comment: Right, the first two function clauses are unchanged, as in the question.

Comment: @legoscia Ah, ok, missed that. But to be nit picky the first clause is actually a different function, `calc_checksum/1`, while the loop function is `calc_checksum/2`.

Answer (score 2):

If you process several values in once you can even speed up little bit more than [Robert's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77617/rvirding) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11837875/49197):

```
calc_checksum(<<W1:16/little, W2:16/little, W3:16/little, W4:16/little, Rest/bytes>>, Acc)->
    calc_checksum(Rest, Acc+W1+W2+W3+W4);
calc_checksum(<<W:16/little,Rest/bytes>>, Acc) ->
    calc_checksum(Rest, Acc+W);
calc_checksum(<<>>, Acc) -> Acc band 16#FFFF.
```

Comment: Good one. Tried it and it actually speed my app by about 10% !